# Select from another table and count from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Given these 2 tables, partial_match and status:

```
   partial_match p      
    id | name
    ----------
    1  | a
    1  | b
    2  | c
    3  | d
    4  | e

   status s
    name | code
    ------------
    a    | YES
    b    | NO
    c    | YES
    c    | MAYBE
    d    | NO
    d    | MAYBE
    e    | YES
```

I'd like a query to return the partial_match ids where the id occurs in partial_match only once, and name has a code with 'YES' in status. So from the data above, query would return ids '2' and '4'.

Comment: Please explain why id = 2 is a match given that it is associated with _two_ codes YES and NO.

Comment: Name can be associated with multiple codes, with a match being at least one code = YES.

Comment: So the requirement is 2 or more total codes, one of which is YES?  Is that right?

Comment: No. "Can be" associated, not "must be" associated. Name can have 1 or more codes. Added id 4, name E to clarify.

Comment: Then for what reason is id = 1 being excluded?

Comment: Because id = 1 has more than 1 row in partial_match.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Count` function with partition by clause to find the counts of ids from 'partial_match' table, then using `Exists` with a correlated subquery you can check if the id have a 'YES` value in 'status' table, check the following:

```
Select P.id From
(
  Select id, name, COUNT(id) Over (Partition By id) cn 
  from partial_match
) P
Where Exists(Select 1 From status S Where S.name = P.name And S.code = 'YES')
And P.cn = 1
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8e8680a6d0210a4c01e462df5a68d070).

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM partial_match p
INNER JOIN status s
    ON s.name = p.name
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) = 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.code = 'YES' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest so far. But I forgot to clarify name can occur in status > 1. I've edited original post. Your solution does exclude id occurring > 1 in partial_match, but it also excludes where name occurs > 1 in status.

Comment: @ChrisC Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.id AS id 
FROM 
    partial_match a
    JOIN
    status b
ON a.name=b.name AND b.code='YES'
```

Comment: This would also return `1`.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    partial_match.id as id
FROM partial_match
JOIN status on status.name = partial_match.name and status.code = 'YES'
GROUP BY partial_match.id
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.